# Print Revit to PDF using Design Automation API - Not allow to printer settings, any other workaround or solution

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am using forge **Forge - Design Automation API (beta) V3** in my Revit-Add which prints pdf from .rvt file. But using APIs there are some restriction on print settings. Is there any other way to implement print pdfs from .rvt's using design automation API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment printing is not supported by Revit Design Automation V3 yet for security reasons.

However as a temporary workaround you can exportto Dwg and then use AutoCAD Design Automation API to export to Pdf. See [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-generate-dynamic-number-output-design-automation-revit-v3?linkId=64185910) and [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/tutorials/convert-dwg-to-pdf/) for details.

My colleague is currently working on a sample demonstrating this process and will update this answer when it’s ready.